# Update a Firestore document with its ID using Laravel-Firebase Package

Tags: laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can anyone please point me on how to update a firestore document with its id. I am able to create a document and update it using the laravel-firebase package by kreait.

My below code creates the document on firestore. However, how do I update this same document with the document reference or id.

```
$groupsRef = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('groups');

$groupData = [
                'groupAdmin'            => auth()->user()->id."_".auth()->user()->name,
                'groupDescription'      => $request->group_description,
                'groupIcon'             => $image,
                'groupId'               => '',
                'groupMembers'          => [
                    auth()->user()->id."_".auth()->user()->name
                ],
                'groupName'             => $request->group_name,
                'recentMessage'         => '',
                'recentMessageSender'   => '',
                'recentMessageTime'     => ''
            ];

            $groupsRef->add($groupData);
```

The below implementation updates the document with its name and not its reference.

```
$document  = $groupsRef->document($request->group_name);
$groupId = $document->id();

$updatedGroupData = [
            'groupAdmin'            => auth()->user()->id."_".auth()->user()->name,
            'groupDescription'      => $request->group_description,
            'groupIcon'             => $request->hasFile('groupIcon') ? $image : '',
            'groupId'               => $groupId,
            'groupMembers'          => [
                auth()->user()->id."_".auth()->user()->name
            ],
            'groupName'             => $request->group_name,
            'recentMessage'         => '',
            'recentMessageSender'   => '',
            'recentMessageTime'     =>  ''
        ];

        $updatedFitfam = $document->update($updatedGroupData);
```

Comment: Try `$documentRef = $groupsRef->document($document->id());` instead of `$document  = $groupsRef->document($request->group_name);`

Comment: @RohitKharche $request->group_name is the name of the group being created. After creating the group, I want to fetch the document reference for that group. `$document->id()` provides the name, i know that but what i want is the reference e.g `QoN4AguuzIM705IOSQobXSpsfT83`

Comment: The group your are stating is a document or a part of your app's analogy ? If you want to get the `DocumentReference` of the document added you can collect it this way `$groupDoc = $groupsRef->add($groupData);` and use it in this way `$document = $groupsRef->document($groupDoc->id());`

Comment: Group is basically a collection. This collection will have many documents. The document structure contains a key `groupId`. The value of this `groupId` should be updated with the document reference. My point is there `$groupDoc->id()` produces the group name. What i want is the document uid, not name.

Comment: Check [this example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/v0.194.0/Firestore/samples/V1/FirestoreClient/update_document.php) for updating the document

Comment: Does that resolve your issue ?

Comment: No, It doesn't. Like I said, i already know how to update the document. However, I want to have the uid as part of the data.

Comment: Updated the code as per your Error

Answer (score 1):

The Firestore [add](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) return the document reference from where you can get the document id. Then update as following :

```
$groupsRef = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('groups');

$groupData = [
                'groupAdmin'            => auth()->user()->id."_".auth()->user()->name,
                'groupDescription'      => $request->group_description,
                'groupIcon'             => $image,
                'groupId'               => '',
                'groupMembers'          => [
                    auth()->user()->id."_".auth()->user()->name
                ],
                'groupName'             => $request->group_name,
                'recentMessage'         => '',
                'recentMessageSender'   => '',
                'recentMessageTime'     => ''
            ];

$docId = $groupsRef->add($groupData);


$updatedGroupData = [
            'groupAdmin'            => auth()->user()->id."_".auth()->user()->name,
            'groupDescription'      => $request->group_description,
            'groupIcon'             => $request->hasFile('groupIcon') ? $image : '',
            'groupId'               => $groupId,
            'groupMembers'          => [
                auth()->user()->id."_".auth()->user()->name
            ],
            'groupName'             => $request->group_name,
            'recentMessage'         => '',
            'recentMessageSender'   => '',
            'recentMessageTime'     =>  ''
        ];

        $updatedFitfam = $document->update($docId->id());
```

If you want to get the document from the `$groupsRef` using `$request->group_name` then use this workaround that should work:

```
$groupsRef = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('groups');
$document = $groupsRef->document($request->group_name);
$snapshot = $document->get();

if ($snapshot->exists()) {
    $existingData = $snapshot->data();
    $updatedGroupData = [
        'groupAdmin'            => auth()->user()->id."_".auth()->user()->name,
        'groupDescription'      => $request->group_description,
        'groupIcon'             => $request->hasFile('groupIcon') ? $image : '',
        'groupMembers'          => array_merge(
            $existingData['groupMembers'] ?? [], 
            [auth()->user()->id."_".auth()->user()->name]
        ),
        'recentMessage'         => $existingData['recentMessage'] ?? ' ',
        'recentMessageSender'   => $existingData['recentMessageSender'] ?? ' ',
        'recentMessageTime'     => $existingData['recentMessageTime'] ?? ' '
    ];

    $document->update($updatedGroupData);
}
```

Reference taken from this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data)

Comment: `$document  = $groupsRef->document($request->group_name)` throws an error even when the document actually exists. if I update using the `update` keyword it throws an error but if i update using `set` keyword, it works but the data is added twice.

Comment: @SharadaSharma Updated the code as per your Error